# Sorted Insert Doubly Linked List

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to make an insertion sort function so that it will sort itself out and then it can display itself in ascending order from top to bottom, and also descending order from bottom to top. It can display sorted from top to bottom ascending, but not descending from bottom to top. Any help?

```
void DoublyLinkedList::insert(int v){
    Node* p = new Node;
    p->data = v;
    p->next = nullptr;
    p->prev = nullptr;
    if(top == nullptr || top->data > p->data){
        p->next = top;
        top = p;
    }
    else{
        bottom = top;
        while(bottom->next != nullptr && bottom->next->data < p->data){
            bottom = bottom->next;
        }
        bottom->next->prev = p;
        p->next = bottom->next;
        bottom->next = p;
        p->prev = bottom->prev;
        bottom->prev = p;
    }   
    size++
}
```

Comment: Don't you miss a `top->prev = p`?

Comment: And what happens if the new nodes value is larger than the current last node? Your loop doesn't handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons for the loop to exit; either `bottom->next` is null or `bottom->next->data >= p->data`.

The code after the loop assumes that the latter was the reason for exiting, but consider what happen when the item to insert is greater than all the elements in the list.